# "git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)" when installing the dependencies from xero-python-oauth2-starter-master

Tags: python, github, pip, xero-api

I am trying to use xero-python-oauth2-starter-master but I cant get past the first step!
I am on Windows and i have installed python 3.8, Visual Studio Code (I also tried this with the Anaconda suit) and latest Git.

When i try to run the dependencies on `requirments.txt` I get the error `Permission denied`. Please see below This is from using Windows PowerShell (also tried from cmd, Anaconda PowerShell and Anaconda CMD)

```
PS C:\Users\m.*\OneDrive\Python\xero-python-oauth2-starter-master> pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting flask
  Using cached Flask-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
Collecting Flask-Session
  Cloning https://github.com/SqrtMinusOne/flask-session.git (to revision 560d00f1a84a9924d788a4f4e1ef35c5cf94c76d) to c:\users\m.*\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-d803d7fn\flask-session
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/SqrtMinusOne/flask-session.git 'C:\Users\m.*\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d803d7fn\Flask-Session'
  Running command git checkout -q 560d00f1a84a9924d788a4f4e1ef35c5cf94c76d
  Running command git submodule update --init --recursive -q
  git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.
  fatal: clone of 'git@github.com:mitsuhiko/flask-sphinx-themes.git' into submodule path 'C:/Users/m.*/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-d803d7fn/Flask-Session/docs/_themes' failed
  Failed to clone 'docs/_themes'. Retry scheduled
  git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.
  fatal: clone of 'git@github.com:mitsuhiko/flask-sphinx-themes.git' into submodule path 'C:/Users/m.*/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-d803d7fn/Flask-Session/docs/_themes' failed
  Failed to clone 'docs/_themes' a second time, aborting
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: git submodule update --init --recursive -q Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 20.2.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\m.*\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Contents of `requirments.txt`

```
flask
# Werkzeug<1.0  # flask-session not compatible
# see https://github.com/fengsp/flask-session/pull/114
# using patched version of flask-session
git+https://github.com/SqrtMinusOne/flask-session.git@560d00f1a84a9924d788a4f4e1ef35c5cf94c76d#egg=Flask-Session
# Werkzeug<1.0  # flask-oauthlib not compatible
# using patched version of flask-oauthlib
git+https://github.com/ageis/flask-oauthlib.git@c5ea3ace957ceeeeab3cfb6556f32685ff292eab#egg=Flask-OAuthlib

# Use development version of xero-python
#git+ssh://git@github.com/xero-github/xero-python.git@020f780b4e2b48cb33746ae19ddab9fdf128e626#egg=xero-python
xero-python==0.5.1
```

Comment: Edit `requirements.txt`, change all entries of `git@github.com:` to `https://github.com/` should correct the permission issue, or simply modify any usage of `git+ssh://git@` to `git+http://`.

Comment: I don't have `git@github.com:` or `git+ssh://git@`

Comment: You don't, but one of the dependencies listed, `flask-session`, does via its [`.gitmodules`](https://github.com/SqrtMinusOne/flask-session/blob/560d00f1a84a9924d788a4f4e1ef35c5cf94c76d/.gitmodules).

Comment: I dont understand what i must do

Comment: So because of that dependency it continued to give an error so i added the below on ~/.gitconfig `[url "https://"]
 insteadOf = ssh://git@
 insteadOf = git@
 
[url "https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sphinx-themes.git"]
 insteadOf = git@github.com:mitsuhiko/flask-sphinx-themes.git` so its not really a solution but it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`git config url.<URL>.insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf):

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf "git@"
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf "ssh://git@"
```

This way every `git@` and `ssh://git@` will be replaced with `https://`.

*Upd*

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf "git@github.com:"

git config --global url."https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sphinx-themes.git".insteadOf "git@github.com:mitsuhiko/flask-sphinx-themes.git"
```

Comment: I did that and now i get this error `fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com:mitsuhiko/flask-sphinx-themes.git/': URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`  This is the original in the git sub-module `git@github.com:mitsuhiko/flask-sphinx-themes.git`

Comment: i just replaced the whole thing to the correct format in .gitconfig and it worked ok. Thank you

Comment: Oops, sorry, it must be `https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sphinx-themes.git`. Added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can resolve this by setting up your SSH keys for your github profile.

Please check that your SSH keys are setup for your github profile?
https://github.com/settings/keys

We ran into some issues with the current version of Flask-Session and had to point to a specific commit and download that code into our project. But in order to do that your SSH keys need to be config.

https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh